# Where to change text for Mailing List Form errors

Tags: forms

I'm using the mailing list module as a newsletter signup form.  I want to edit the error text that is shown if the user doesn't fill out the form correctly.  Here is the error text:

> The form you submitted contained the following errors
>
> - The username you chose is not available
> - List item the screen name you chose is not available
> - The email you chose is not available
> - Please type both words that appear in the image

I'm not using captcha so the last bullet doesn't make any sense.  I simply with to remove that text.  Can someone please tell me where to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit the actual text of the 'message' then you need to edit the language files here: system/expressionengine/language/english/

If you want more control over the design of the templates etc then check out the Custom System Messages add-on http://dvt.ee/csm ($12)

Comment: That is exactly what I asked for.  Unfortunately what I meant to ask is how to delete one of those items? 

In the language file if I set the variable to an empty string the bullet still shows up.  So I guess I need to know where to remove it from the code.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

OR - go to CP -> Tools -> Utilities -> Translation Utility
you need to edit "mailinglist_lang.php"